# grid prefab not showing on mobile

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

My game creates a grid view (contains many grid prefabs) upon running. The grids are shown nicely on unity editor but none was shown on mobile build.

Image below is the blue grids shown on unity editor. Mobile build doesn't get any blue grids. It just shows the background below the blue grids.

[image: on unity editor]

On mobile, grids are disappear. My code for showing grids is as below

```
void createGrid()
{
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++)
        {
            GameObject grid = GameObject.Instantiate(gridBoxSample);
            gridPrefabs.Add(grid);
            grid.transform.parent = currentMap.transform;
            float gridSize = grid.GetComponent<GridBoxAction>().normalRender.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x;
            float mapSize = currentMap.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x;
            grid.transform.position = new Vector3(-mapSize / 2 + gridSize / 2 + gridSize * j, mapSize / 2 - gridSize / 2 - (gridSize * i), -4);
            grid.SetActive(true);
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Since I dont know how to debug unity game on mobile (i deploy to ios build) I cant figure out what is the problem here. 
Any clues for solving problem is very very appreciated!

Comment: You wanna post a picture of what the grid looks like in iOS? Also, it would be good to post your code instead of a picture. If someone wants to run the code to find the problem, they wont spend 5 hours typing a code from a picture....

Comment: thanks for reminding. I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after times headbutting over my laptop I figured out it was some logic bug that prevent my prefabs from being instantiated. First time strugging I thought that it was Instantiate() bug but it was not. Instantiate will work on any platform, why it doesn't show itself up is just only because of the logic.